# Mount does not limit the size of drive

Tags: mount, files, filesystem

I set a `ramdisk` via

```
sudo mount ramfs -t ramfs /media/typicalramdisk/ -o size=1M
```

Then I put files inside it. They exceeded `1 MB` and I still could place files in this drive.

I tried `1m`, `900k` and a few other options. None of them limited the drive.

Does `mount` limit the size of the mounted disk in any way?

Comment: The limit to ramfs is your physical RAM itself.  See:  https://wiki.debian.org/ramfs  In other words, you cannot limit ramfs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create the ramdisk using **`tmpfs`**, not `ramfs`.

`ramfs` is an older implementation and lacks size checking (see [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/tmpfs.txt)).

So your command will become :

```
sudo mount tmpfs -t tmpfs /media/typicalramdisk/ -o size=1M
```

Comment: `tmpfs` is great. But it might use swap instead of pure ram.